# Group Action Based Problem

Tags: group-theory

G be a group of order 77 acting on a set of order 20 elements.Show that there is an element b in S such that the orbit of b consists of b only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $b\in S$, write $O(b) = \{gb : g\in G\}$ and $G_b = \{g\in G : gb = b\}$, then there is a bijection
$$
G/G_b \to O(b) \text{ given by } hG_b \mapsto hb
$$
In particular, $|O(b)| \mid 77$ for each $b\in S$. Since $O(b) \subset S$, it follows that $|O(b)| \in \{1,7,11\}$ for all $b\in S$. Now $S$ is the disjoint union of such orbits, so we end up with an equation of the form
$$
20 = n_1+7n_7+11n_{11}
$$
where $n_i \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ denotes the number of orbits of size $i$. If $n_1 = 0$, then this equation has no solution, and so $n_1 \geq 1$. This is what you need.

Comment: I couldn't understand the part' S is the union of such orbits',will please elaborate..thank you

Comment: Two orbits are either disjoint or they coincide, so they partition $S$. In other words, the relation $$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow \exists g\in G \text{ such that } x=gy$$ is an equivalence relation on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Use the class equation for a group action.